# xpath - scraping data inside an inframe

Tags: php, iframe, xpath, screen-scraping

I've done web scraping before but it was never this complex. I want to grab param values inside an iframe.

Example Code:

```
  <iframe width="100%" scrolling="no" height="320px" frameborder="0" src="http://carriers.993low.com/fqoyJxxS.php">
  <object id="player" width="100%" height="100%" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="http://merhad.333low.com/player.swf" bgcolor="#000000" name="player" tabindex="0">
      <param name="allowfullscreen" value="true">
      <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always">
      <param name="seamlesstabbing" value="true">
      <param name="wmode" value="opaque">
      <param name="flashvars" value="http://merhad.333low.com/fqoyJxxS-2c2MSx-wGYmS3T1pkggIeiK7wpA7BbXXcK2sC4XYWehpBDV6CAK7CFH/s=awcmxqt5gYntLqHJ9ceP.flv">
    </object>
  </iframe>
```

I want to return the value of the param which is inside the object with xpath.

Comment: An iframe is a node just the same as any other, and so is the object, and its parameters.  Just because HTML makes them magic, does not mean they are anything more than normal markup.

Comment: $xpath2->query("//iframe/object/param[@name='flashvars']/@value")->item(0)->nodeValue

Comment: To be honest I'm getting crazy tonight. I can't figure out why this it's not working.

Comment: It might be a good idea to drop some of the more elaborate selector types of things, and seeing what you get... that way you can see exactly what part of the query is causing problems. Something quick would bet to see if you are getting at the param nodes like this: `//iframe/object/param/@value`

Answer (score 0):

nodeValue is not available for attributes. Try:

```
$xpath2->query("//iframe/object/param[@name='flashvars']/@value")->item(0)->value;
```

or

```
$xpath2->query("//iframe/object/param[@name='flashvars']")->item(0)->getAttribute('value');
```